How to create a VM in xcp-ng?
I want to create a VM by using a VM template on xcp-ng 8.2. I was able to do this yesterday but today, the same command isn't working. I'm new to server administration so I want to believe this fix should be relatively easy.
I followed this YouTube tutorial XCP-ng xe CLI creating a VM. This video, I presume, is based on this article. Yesterday, I hit a snag so I decided to delete everything I created using the tutorial, and start afresh. Now, I'm unable to create the VM using the template although I did that yesterday without any issues. In the tutorial, Rocky Linux was used but I used Ubuntu Focal Fossa yesterday. The SR type is ISO. This is the command I ran yesterday and today:
xe vm-install template="Ubuntu Focal Fossa 20.04" new-name-label="${vm_name}" sr-uuid=${sr_iso_uuid}

The error message I'm getting today is:
You attempted an operation that was not allowed.
reason: Cannot copy a VM's disks to an ISO SR


According to the creator, link here, any regular SR other than an ISO should work.
